# Filter strings with numbers in a range and change format

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file with lines in the following pattern:

```
136x2340+1564+0
```

that is, `<N1>x<N2>+<N3>+<N4>`.

I'd like to filter (maybe with `grep`) all lines such that `N1` range is from `a` to `b` **and** `N2` range is from `c` to `d`.

The constants `a,b,c,d` depend on my problem. I'll fix them in the script.

I tried `egrep '^([0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9]+)'` but the output shows

```
136x2340+1564+0
835x428+355+1780
817x406+186+747
114x1533+1256+456
```

that is, also shows lines with `N2` with 4 digits (I supposed only 3 digits).

**edit:** also I'd like to replace `x` by `,` (comma), the first `+` sign by  (empty space) and the second `+` sign by `,` (comma) so the output should be

```
N1,N2 N3,N4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In grep extended regular expression (ERE) syntax, `+` is a quantifier meaning 'one or more of the preceding atom'. To match `+` literally in this context, you need to escape it:

```
egrep '^([0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9]\+)' file
835x428+355+1780
817x406+186+747
```

If you want to make *substitutions*, then `grep` really isn't the right tool - however if your version of `sed` has a similar extended regex mode you could use that:

```
sed -En 's/([0-9]{3})x([0-9]{3})\+([0-9]{1,})\+([0-9]{1,})/\1,\2 \3,\4/p' file
835,428 355,1780
817,406 186,747
```

If you only have basic regular expressions, the escaping becomes harder to read:

```
sed -n 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)x\([0-9]\{3\}\)+\([0-9]\{1,\}\)+\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1,\2 \3,\4/p' file
835,428 355,1780
817,406 186,747
```

Comment: **scape!!!** How could I forget it?? Thanks so much. So easy!

Comment: please, could you see edited post?

Comment: Perfect. Now you saved my day. `-En` works good.

Comment: How to filter if lower bound `a` contains 3 digits and upper bound `b` could contain 3 or 4. In other words, I'd like to filter now any line such that `N1xN2` belongs to Cartesian region `[150,1100] x [200,1200]`?

Comment: @Sigur you should probably switch to a tool that supports arithmetic (rather than strictly lexical) comparisons - such as `awk` or `perl`